# AngularJS - Input change outside directive value passed in to directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a beginner to AngularJs and I cannot figure out how to retrieve data from outside a directive. I have various input being updated and I need the directive to take this data and work with it.

For example, in the code below, the first input field is hooked up to the directive and works fine, but without putting the directive attribute on the second input field, how can the data typed in that field be updated in the directive?

HTML:

```html
<div ng-app="myDirective">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test1" my-directive>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test2">
</div>
```

Directive:

```js
angular.module('myDirective', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                console.log('New Value from field 1: ' + v);
                //console.log('New Value from field 2: ' + ???);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your directive does not create a new scope, the `scope` variable inside the directive's link method points to the outer scope containing the two inputs.  So you can replace:

```
//console.log('New Value from field 2: ' + ???);
```

with

```
console.log('New Value from field 2: ' + scope.test2);
```

Make sure to enter some data in the second input when testing or it will print `undefined`.

[Here is a working <kbd>fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/TJreh/)

---

**EDIT**: If you did need to use isolate scope in your directive, you could do the following in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test1" my-directive="test2">
<input type="text" ng-model="test2">
```

The difference here is now passing in the `test2` model into the directive, and setting up a binding to it in your directive by adding the `scope` property:

```
scope: {
    otherInput: '=myDirective'
    // this tells the directive to bind the local variable `otherInput`
    // to whatever the `my-directive` attribute value is. In this case, `test2`
},
```

This allows you to access passed values in your directive.  You would then change your `$watch`es as follows:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
    console.log('New Value from field 1: ' + v);
    console.log('New Value from field 2: ' + scope.otherInput);
});

// notice the syntax for watching a scope variable
scope.$watch('otherInput', function (v) {
    console.log('New Value from field 1: ' + scope.test1);
    console.log('New Value from field 2: ' + v);
});
```

I've included this in my fiddle as another example, `test3` and `test4`.

Comment: Oh whoa, I did not expect that would work. However, the directive only notices a change in the first text field. How could the second text field result in the $watch being invoked?

Comment: You would just need to add another watch on `test2`. I've updated the fiddle to show that.

Comment: I see. I just updated my code and it works! One last question though, if there are more than two inputs, lets say test3, how would that work?

Comment: Then you would just add another watch for that input. I've updated the fiddle again, have a look.

Answer (score 5):

I could have explained that in text, but I think it would be much better if you watch these 3 videos by [john lindquist](https://twitter.com/johnlindquist):

- [Isolate Scope "@"](http://www.egghead.io/video/7X5vx-n7Nxs)
- [Isolate Scope "="](http://www.egghead.io/video/O9iVkfQJauQ)
- [Isolate Scope "&"](http://www.egghead.io/video/mZGgNPTHc2Q)

And [summary](http://www.egghead.io/video/97pv_kiYhv4).

They are really short (~4min each) but very simple and useful.

PS: by the way, i recommend you to watch others as well. They are all short and precise, loved them.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs directive lets you to use scope with different ways and do many cool things you need.You can use your scope as not **inherit, inherit and isolated**.If you use scope as isolated,you can pass variables and bind it wherever you want.

here are 2 cool articles with examples, which can help you

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/change-variable-from-outside-of-directive.html

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/bind-variable-inside-angularjs-directive-isolated-scope.html